# After clicking "Like" button on my App different icon and name shows on the person timeline

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps

I created an app on https://www.facebook.com/#!/iakverzekeringen with name EK 2012 actie and logo of EK 2012. When someone click on like button placed in app it is shown with IAK Company logo and name IakApp which I have no clue where it comes from. Do you know why in place of the logo of the App and name of the App the API presents the logo of the Company and name that is not clear to me? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your opengraph meta tags are well implemented.

Check the documentation over here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

there is a tool to generate opengraph tags.